# HPLIP complains about missing dependency which is already installed

Tags: linux-mint, hplip

I am on Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon. I downloaded the latest version of HPLIP from official page.

I ran `sh hplip-3.16.7.run` and got this now:

```
INSTALL MISSING REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES
-------------------------------------
note: Installation of dependencies requires an active internet connection.
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: libtool (libtool - Library building support services)


CHECKING FOR NETWORK CONNECTION
-------------------------------
Network connection present.


RUNNING PRE-PACKAGE COMMANDS
----------------------------
sudo dpkg --configure -a (Pre-depend step 1)
sudo apt-get install --yes --force-yes -f (Pre-depend step 2)
sudo apt-get update (Pre-depend step 3)
OK


DEPENDENCY AND CONFLICT RESOLUTION
----------------------------------
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes libtool'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: A required dependency 'libtool (libtool - Library building support services)' is still missing.


RUNNING POST-PACKAGE COMMANDS
-----------------------------
OK


RE-CHECKING DEPENDENCIES
------------------------
error: A required dependency 'libtool (libtool - Library building support services)' is still missing.
error: Installation cannot continue without this dependency.
error: Please manually install this dependency and re-run this installer.
```

But it obviously is installed, proof:

```
apt-cache policy libtool
```

gives

```
libtool:
  Installed: 2.4.6-0.1
  Candidate: 2.4.6-0.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.4.6-0.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I am confused now. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem on Linux Mint 18 with Cinnamon.

To fix it, I installed `libtool-bin` and restarted the installation of `hplip` again. This time it prompted me to uninstall the previous installation, which I did. After successful installation and reboot, I was able to set up my printer and everything was ok.